# How can I fix the following error retrieving a document using firebase admin?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am unable to get a single document from my firestore database. I can pull the data just fine on client side using angularfire2. But when I use the following code in cloud functions I get a random object. This the the following database schema

```
/networks/hzlNpVEB9nOKRdPG/companyProfiles/M6nKSjsnA9yyhvnvfB8oD/userProfiles/820RGKrdhhjoF9Ba6Zf
```

This is the code

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();
let profilesRef = db.collection("/networks/${networkProfileId}/companyProfiles/${companyProfileId}/userProfiles").doc(user.uid).get()
         .then(doc =>{
                if(doc.exists){
                    res.status(200).send({data:doc.data()});
                }

            })
```

this is the current returned object

```
{}
​
<prototype>: {…}
​​
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
​​
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
​​
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
​​
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
​​
__proto__: Getter & Setter
​​
constructor: function Object()
​​
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
​​
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
​​
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
​​
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
​​
toSource: function toSource()
​​
toString: function toString()
​​
valueOf: function valueOf()
```

Comment: You're using double quotes (`"`) in your path, but seem to be also using template literals. You probably want to put that in backticks: ``collection(`/networks/${networkProfileId}/companyProfiles/${companyProfileId}/userProfiles`)``.

Comment: fixed that its now `networks/${networkProfileId}/companyProfiles/${companyProfileId}/userProfiles`).doc(`${user.uid}` but i still get the same error. but if I hard code the values in the string it works just fine. I also checked if the variables have values and they do

Comment: What does your call to `admin.initializeApp()` look like?

Comment: admin.initializeApp(); Thats all I have. According to the new update you know longer need the extra parameters. If I do `('networks/453j5hn4j3k/companyProfiles/dsadiodisa988/userProfiles').doc('fdsfds7f678ds')` that works perfectly. Seems when I add variables it doesn't work. the following wont work 
 `collection(\`/networks/${networkProfileId}/companyProfiles/${companyProfileId}/userProfiles\`).doc(user.uid)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the straw that broke the camels back. Had over 5 developers look at this and not even the google engineer was able to help. Something so basic and not functioning. Reverted over 6 versions. Rebuilt the app in angularjs and sql and worked just fine.